# Should the value be updated at the end or at the beginning of while loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

I was practicing the binary search algorithm and the algorithm gave the same results when the value of mid was updated at the beginning or at the end of the while loop that iterates till `start <= end` and `mid = (start + end)/2` knowing that the value doesn't overflow.

Included header files are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

The main function is:

```
int main(){
    vector<int> arr = {1,3,5,6,6,7,8,9,15};
    int size = arr.size();
    int element = 5;

    // binarySearch(vector<int> arr, int size, key)
    int index = binarySearch(arr, size, element);
    cout << element << " found at index " << index << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The function code:

`key` is the element to search for in the vector array `arr` and `size` is the number of elements in the array.

```
    int start = 0, end = size - 1;
    int mid = (start + end)/2;
    while(start <= end){
        // updating the value of mid
        mid = (start + end)/2;
        if(arr[mid] == key){
            return mid;
        }
        else if(key < arr[mid]){
            end = mid - 1;
        }
        else{
            start = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The code when `mid` is updated at the end of while loop is:

```
int binarySearch(vector<int> arr, int size, int key){
    int start = 0, end = size - 1;
    int mid = (start + end)/2;
    while(start <= end){
        if(arr[mid] == key){
            return mid;
        }
        else if(key < arr[mid]){
            end = mid - 1;
        }
        else{
            start = mid + 1;
        }
        // updating the value of mid
        mid = (start + end)/2;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Does updating `mid` at the end or beginning actually make any difference??

Comment: Totally depends on when you want `mid` to have the new value. Work that out with pen and paper and you'll have your answer in no time.

Comment: Do not tag `dsa`. Did you read what the `dsa` tag is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really doesn't matter where you do it as long as it's calculated before used inside the loop.

- Placing it *last* in the loop will therefore require a pre-calculation before the loop so you have the same formula in two places. If you can avoid that, it's usually preferable, since you don't want to have to modify the calculation in multiple places in case you need to change it later.
- Placing it *first* in the loop like you do in the first snippet would for the reason mentioned above be preferable. You can then skip the pre-calculation that you do before the loop and end up with only one.

In the below example, I'm not sending in the size of the `vector` to the function, since the `vector` has a `size()` function that can be used. That function returns a value of type `std::size_t` so I'll use that type to avoid getting warnings from the compiler about comparing *signed* variables with *unsigned* (`std::size_t` can't hold negative values). That also means that I can't just do `size() - 1` since taking the size of an empty `vector` and subtracting `1` would "wrap around" and become a really huge value. I therefore set `end = size()` and use `while (start < end)` in the loop instead (as well as assigning `end = mid` instead of `end = mid - 1` in the loop).

I've also changed the order of the comparisons a bit. If `arr` holds many values, I'm assuming that the test for equality will be needed very few times so I instead test if `key < arr[mid]` or `arr[mid] < key`. If none of those are `true`, they must be equal.

Example:

```cpp
constexpr std::size_t not_found = static_cast<std::size_t>(-1);

size_t binarySearch(const std::vector<int>& arr, int key) {
    std::size_t start = 0, end = arr.size();

    while (start < end) {
        std::size_t mid = (start + end) / 2;

        if (key < arr[mid]) {
            end = mid;
        } else if (arr[mid] < key) {
            start = mid + 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return not_found;
}
```

I also added a constant, `not_found`, which can be used to determine if the value we searched for was found or not. Example usage:

```cpp
std::size_t index = binarySearch(arr, element);

if(index == not_found) {
    std::cout << element << " was not found\n";
} else {
    std::cout << element << " found at index " << index << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `mid` value at the beginning or end of the loop should not make any difference. In your code example, the `mid` value is set prior to entering the loop and once again after determining in which direction the search should go. You could eliminate the `mid` declaration prior to loop and move the bottom loop `mid` declaration to the top of the loop and accomplish the same thing.

Also, don't get into the habit of using `using namespace std;` instead make the individual declarations  `using std:vector;` and `using std:cout;` or simply insert the `std::` in the front of the function like `std::cout << "Test" << std:endl;`

Answer (score 1):

in your code you initialize mid as `int mid = (start + end) / 2` in booth of the example before starting the while loop. that make your two code same where mid value always `(start + end) / 2` is same for every same iteration for the loops. if you change `int mid = (start + end) / 2` to `int mid` then in second example of code will provide error and first will not.

Comment: @user19117411 Every other comment and answer are right, but the correct approach is addressed in this answer and this is the solution to your question. While `mid` is dependent on usage or algorithm flow, because in your case the flow is identical, the real difference comes in readability and/or optimization (talking in general to any other code in a similar situation to yours). When adding it all together and the location where you assign it as well as the many times you recalculate it as well as readability, optimization and simplicity, this answer says it all: only the first version works.